# lxml check if text is present after element (not only tail)

Tags: python, text, lxml

I'm parsing an xml document containing a specific tag (`<question>`) embedded under another one (`<Turn>`), and I need to check if there is text after the closing tag `</question>` until the closing parent tag `</Turn>`. The thing is that there might be some other tags between `</question>` and `</Turn>`, or newlines, spaces, or even all of the above, thus retrieving only the question's tail is not enough.

Here is some example of a part of a xml file I'm working on:

```
<root>
<Turn speaker="spk2" startTime="5121.203" endTime="5136.265">
<question startline="8321" endline="8326">
<Sync time="5121.203"/>
some text
<Sync time="5126.531"/>
<Sync time="5127.662"/>
other text?</question><question startline="8326" endline="8326">
here are some other words?
</question> 
<Sync time="5128.514"/>
THIS IS SOME TEXT I WANT TO GET <anothertag att="2"/> SOME OTHER TEXT
<annoyingtag att="blah"/>
AND THIS TOO

</Turn>

<Turn>
<question>
this is a question?
</question>
this is not, I want to get this text.
</Turn>

<Turn>
There could be a turn with no question here.
</Turn>

<Turn>
<question>
and then another with a question?
</question>
followed by
<Sync/>
other text

but also
<Event/>
other tags

<Who/>
and I want to get all this text.
</Turn>
</root>
```

I am processing the xml with lxml in python. When I want to check if there is some text between `</question>` and `</Turn>`, I am already in a for loop processing questions, such as:

```
Turns = rootnode.findall(".//Turn")
for Turn in Turns:
    questions = Turn.findall(".//question")
    for question in question:
        if question == questions[-1]:
            #This is where I will insert the code trying to find if there is some text following the question tag.
```

In this case I tried to get the tail both with `question.tail()` and this other method `question.xpath("//text()")[1]`, but in both cases I do not see all the text between the last `</question>` and `</Turn>` (either none or some part of it).

I also tried to do it on the raw file with a regex, but since many things can appear between the two closing tags, I ended up with a regex with nested quantifiers and a problem of catastrophic backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

This may work if the sync tag is always there:

```
xml = """<Turn speaker="spk2" startTime="5121.203" endTime="5136.265">
<question startline="8321" endline="8326">
<Sync time="5121.203"/>
some text
<Sync time="5126.531"/>
<Sync time="5127.662"/>
other text?</question><question startline="8326" endline="8326">
here are some other words?
</question>
<Sync time="5128.514"/>
THIS IS SOME TEXT I WANT TO GET <anothertag att="2"/> SOME OTHER TEXT
<annoyingtag att="blah"/>
AND THIS TOO
</Turn>"""

from lxml.html import fromstring

xml = fromstring(xml)

print(xml.xpath("//question[last()]/following::sync/following::text()"))
```

Which would give you:

```
['\nTHIS IS SOME TEXT I WANT TO GET ', ' SOME OTHER TEXT\n', '\nAND THIS TOO\n']
```

Or:

```
print(xml.xpath("//question[last()]/following::text()"))
```

Which gives you:

```
['\n', '\nTHIS IS SOME TEXT I WANT TO GET ', ' SOME OTHER TEXT\n', '\nAND THIS TOO\n']
```

You could also use a wildcard :

```
 print(xml.xpath("//question[last()]/following::*/following::text()"))
```

Which again would give you:

```
['\nTHIS IS SOME TEXT I WANT TO GET ', ' SOME OTHER TEXT\n', '\nAND THIS TOO\n']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that the Sync tag is _not_ always there. Besides, there can be other tags instead of Sync, such as `<Who>` or `<Event>`.

Comment: If you added a more complicated example it would help.  The last xpath will work regardless what is there but I have no idea of all the possibilities

Comment: Furthermore, when I'm looking for text between `</question>` and `</Turn>` I already identified the `<question>` tag and I am in a for loop going through questions in a Turn. Thus, I was thinking of identifying the last question with `if question == questions[-1]:`, this is where I should apply the XPath. I tried this expression but I don't get anything:

`print(question.xpath("following::*/following::text()"))`

Comment: So basically you want any text after the last question and before the next turn? Can you add the text you want from your input?

Comment: Yes, every text between </question> and </Turn>, no matter if there are tags or not. If it is only space characters (newlines/tabs/spaces), I don't want it.
I don't understand your question though. I only want to check if some text is present there, I don't really care what it is. So I just want the code to indicate if text is present or not.

Comment: But what do you want returned, the question tags that have some text the is no just whitespace? i.e  `[n for n in xml.xpath("//turn//question[last()]") if n.xpath("./following::text()")[0].strip()]`

Comment: What I basically want is this:

   `Turns = rootnode.findall(".//Turn")
    for Turn in Turns:
        questions = Turn.findall(".//question")
        for question in question:
            if question == questions[-1]:
                 if there is some text after </question> and before </Turn>:
                       text_afterq = "yes"
                 else:
                       text_afterq = "no"`